# iOS game lagging after loading view frequently

Tags: iphone, xcode, view

I am developping a relatively simple frame based iphone game, and it runs quite smoothly. However, when I switch views and then back again a couple of times everything starts to lagg severely.

Maybe someone recognizes this as a simple programming problem. (e.g. not setting iVars to nil, not switching views correctly, loading too much variables at the same time, etc.)

NOTE: this happens only after having switched views over 10 times.

Comment: Can you post the code in question? I.E. the code that handles the switching

Comment: I don't have any code for switching; I use interface builder to do that. (Drag a line from a button to a view and then select modal).